useTemplateRef If the binding name is the same as the component name, an error occurs in the component?
When using useTemplateRef to bind a component, an error occurs when the name is the same as the component name (byElInput) and null is returned in a has check in a child component. No error occurs when using a different name.
Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tjpdvz?file=src%2FApp.vue
Everything is running smoothly.

Just import the component capitalized:
import ByElInput from './components/HelloWorld.vue';


Thank you, but may I ask why
